# I want triggers to delete from 2 tables in sql server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, delete-row

I have 2 SQL Server tables (A and B).

I want to delete rows from:
A, when deleting a row in B using one trigger.

And I want to delete rows from:
B, when deleting a row in A using one trigger.

Here is my trigger so far:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER instead_delete
 ON A INSTEAD of DELETE as

 DELETE B 
 FROM B, deleted
 WHERE B.Id = deleted.Id

 DELETE A 
 FROM A, deleted
 WHERE A.Id = deleted.Id
```

And my second trigger:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER after_delete
 ON B AFTER DELETE as

 DELETE A 
 FROM A, deleted
 WHERE A.Id = deleted.Id
```

But it doesn't work correctly.
I get a direct recursion. (instead of triggers do not support direct recursion. the trigger execution failed - this error).

How Can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you using an instead of trigger and not after trigger on table A?
Are these tables related? perhaps a cascade delete option on foreign key will be better

Comment: Take a look at [TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182737.aspx)

Comment: @ZoharPeled I think cascade delete will help me. Thanks.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to delete a hierarchy of records in a self referencing table that had a foreign key contraint. Using an AFTER DELETE trigger didn't work as the foreign key contraint was violated before it got there. Using an INSTEAD OF trigger didn't work as it threw the "INSTEAD OF triggers do not support direct recursion" error. Changing the direct and indirect setting for the database had no effect. I could not find a solution any where. The only solution I could come up with was to use a CTE to select all records in the heirarchy with a depth/level number and use a cursor to delete the records one-by-one from greatest depth upwards to avoid foreign key violations. Here is the example trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[relatedAccountInsteadOfDelete] 
   ON  [dbo].[relatedAccount] 
   INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- log deleted related accounts 
    with relatedAccounts as ( 
        select
            ra1.[guid]
            ,ra1.relatedAccount_guid
        from
            relatedAccount ra1
        inner join 
            deleted d
        on
            d.[guid] = ra1.[guid]
        union all
        select
            ra1.[guid]
            ,ra1.relatedAccount_guid
        from
            relatedAccount ra1
        inner join 
            relatedAccounts ra2
        on
            ra2.[guid] = ra1.relatedAccount_guid
        where
            ra1.relatedAccount_guid is not null
    )
    insert into relatedAccount_history select ra1.* from relatedAccount ra1 inner join relatedAccounts ra2 on ra2.[guid] = ra1.[guid];

    -- delete related entities 
    with relatedAccounts as ( 
        select
            ra1.[guid]
            ,ra1.relatedAccount_guid
        from
            relatedAccount ra1
        inner join 
            deleted d
        on
            d.[guid] = ra1.[guid]
        union all
        select
            ra1.[guid]
            ,ra1.relatedAccount_guid
        from
            relatedAccount ra1
        inner join 
            relatedAccounts ra2
        on
            ra2.[guid] = ra1.relatedAccount_guid
        where
            ra1.relatedAccount_guid is not null
    )
    delete from dbo.relatedEntity where [guid] in (select t1.[guid] from relatedAccounts d inner join dbo.relatedEntity t1 on t1.relatedAccount_guid=d.[guid]);

    -- delete related accounts
    declare @guid uniqueidentifier;

    -- select all accounts to any depth in their hierarchy
    declare relatedAccounts_cursor cursor for
    with relatedAccounts as ( 
        select
             1 as depth
            ,ra1.[guid]
            ,ra1.relatedAccount_guid
        from
            relatedAccount ra1
        inner join 
            deleted d
        on
            d.[guid] = ra1.[guid]
        union all
        select
            ra2.depth + 1 as depth
            ,ra1.[guid]
            ,ra1.relatedAccount_guid
        from
            relatedAccount ra1
        inner join 
            relatedAccounts ra2
        on
            ra2.[guid] = ra1.relatedAccount_guid
        where
            ra1.relatedAccount_guid is not null
    )
    select [guid] from relatedAccounts order by depth desc;

    -- delete accounts from the bottom up to avoid violating foriegn key constraints
    open relatedAccounts_cursor

    fetch next from relatedAccounts_cursor
    into @guid

    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin

        delete from dbo.relatedAccount where [guid] = @guid; 

        fetch next from relatedAccounts_cursor
        into @guid

    end

    close relatedAccounts_cursor;
    deallocate relatedAccounts_cursor;

END
```